# Using Hibernate Criteria to match all items in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class like the following:

```
    public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer articleId;

    @ManyToMany List<Region> regions;
```

Now I get in a search for a list of region ids.

How can I match only articles that have ALL the region ids(more is ok, but partial matches are not). Obviously, I can use `Restrictions.in` to match any, but how do I match them all?

Comment: So you are ok if `regions` in the `Article` is a superset of `regionIds` you want to match. So you may to look at `Conjunction conjun = Restrictions.conjunction();                conjun.add(Restrictions.in("article.regions", region1));conjun.add(Restrictions.in("article.regions", region2))` etc by adding conjunction for each `regionId` in your search list.

Comment: Or simpler way using `HQL` if feasible in your scenario, would be trying out `all elements(...)` keyword like `regions = all elements(searchRegions)` as in **section 1.4.10** in [Hibernate 3,3 HQL Ref](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)